# How to solve Airflow module import issue?

Tags: python, airflow, importerror

I am getting *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named* error in my Airflow DAG file. Directory structure is below. According to my understanding of Python packages and Airflow module management, I added the project_dir to sys.path in DAG file. What should I fix to make the imports work?

```
dags
  |
  | organization_dir
            |
            | project_dir
                      |
                      | __init__.py
                      | common_package
                                |
                                | __init__.py
                                | dag_pipeline_module.py
                                | subpackage
                                        |
                                        | __init__.py
                                        | sub_pkg_module.py
                      |
                      | configs
                                |
                                | __init__.py
                                | table_config.py
                      |
                      | __init__.py
                      | ci_config.py
                      | factory_config.py
                      | project_dag.py
```

**project_dag.py**

Imports here are working fine.

```
import os
import sys

from airflow import DAG

import_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, import_path)


from factory_config import var1,var2
from common_package import DagPipelineFactory    # from dag_pipeline_module.py
```

**factory_config.py**

This is giving an error. If I use full path, then it works fine.

```
import os

import configs as table_configs
from ci_config import var3      # error

# from organization_dir.project_dir.ci_config import var3     # no error
```

**ci_config.py**

```
var3 = None
```

**Error Details**

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/organization_dir/project_dir/factory_config.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/organization_dir/project_dir/factory_config.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ci_config import var3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ci_config'
```

Comment: Where does factory_config.py live in the project tree?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the hierarchy.

Comment: Could you identify which directory (or directories?) is intended to be a package? It looks like your want `project_dir` to be the top-level package, based on the `__init__.py`s. If that's the case, you need to put the directory that the package is in on your Python path (i.e. `organization_dir`), not the package itself.